# shape functions of interpolating a piecewise polynomial with continuous 0-th and 1-st derivatives

Tags: finite-element, interpolation, b-spline

shape functions are the basis functions that interpolate a function in a subdomain using polynomials. linear interpolation is probably the most convenient approach which results in so-called "tent" functions. a combination of tent functions gives any desired piecewise linear interpolation.

The idea can be generalized to polynomial of higher degree. using Lagrange fundamental polynomials, it is easy to derive the shape functions for higher degree interpolation. these shape functions can generate continuous functions at the nodes or "breakpoints". However, the continuity of first derivative is not supported this way, and the function is not "smooth".

**The question**: Can we derive a set of piecewise polynomials $\phi_k(x)$  for which
$$y=\sum_k c_k \phi_k(x)$$
is always not only continuous but has continuous first derivative? (higher order derivatives can be discontinuous).

**Attempts thus far**:
so far, I attempted to obtain the shape functions of a continuous piecewise quadratic function with continuous first derivative by solving a system of equations. The system is obtained by imposing the continuity conditions and the nodal values equality. this way I acquired the shape functions that satisfied all conditions. the problem was that the shape functions were changing and becoming more complicated as the number of breakpoints were increased. I expected something like a "curved tent function" for all elements but was quite different.

**Possible answer:** I assume my question regards B-splines, Bezier or Bernstein polynomials. If it is so, could you provide a basic reference for self reading?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Cubic Hermite spline explains 1D interpolation such that the interpolated function and its first derivative are continuous. In 2D you can achieve this with bicubic interpolation.

Comment: Look up Argyris and Bell elements.